# creating an app in flask-peewee

Tags: python, error-handling, flask, peewee

i am creating an app in flask-peewee for user login , register and logout. all the app are route properly on the url. the problem is occur when i try to post the data than it give an error :-
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
also give a TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

at view.py :-

```
from flask import request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash
from flask_peewee.utils import get_object_or_404, object_list
from app import app
from models import User
from auth import *


@app.route('/join/' , methods=['GET','POST'])
def join(): 

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['username']:
        try:
            user = User.select().where(User.username==request.form['username']).get()
            flash('That username is already taken')
        except User.DoesNotExist:       
            user = User(
                username = request.form['username'],
                email = request.form['email'] )
            user.set_password(request.form['password'] )
            user.save()
            auth.login_user(user)
            return 'dua me yaad rakhna'
#           return render_template('home')
#   else:
#       return 'HAAN G DEKHYa fer'

    return render_template("join.html")
```

at models.py:-

```
from hashlib import md5, sha1
import datetime

from flask_peewee.auth import BaseUser
from peewee import *
from app import db



class User(BaseUser):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    email = CharField()


    class Meta:
        order_by = ('username',)
```

main.py:-

```
from views import *
from app import app
from auth import *



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

app.py :-

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.db import Database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Configuration')

db = Database(app)


def create_tables():
    User.create_table()
```

route.py and auth.py is also defined but it can't display any output. the error is occur.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the FULL stack trace of the error.

Comment: Please include your templates too. And in views.py, please get return to your templates files.